# How to Remove \r and \n from json string in cakephp 3?

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have String like below after doing json_encode

```
[{"pid":1,"name":"Patient1","mobile":"123456789","birthdate":"07/23/1991","address":"57, New Building,\r\nCollege Road,\r\nPune-3545001","created":"2017-09-25T08:14:10+00:00","modified":"2017-09-25T12:27:20+00:00"}]
```

so how can i remove \r and \n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_replace('\r\n', '', $string);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for late